# Estimating incidence and prevalence from demographic data

Tags: references, epidemiology, demography

I'm interested in estimating incidence and prevalence of specific diseases in the USA based on the [NAMCS data set](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/ahcd/ahcd_questionnaires.htm). However, the data set only records patient/prevalence visits - there is no way of calculating the incidence directly from the data set, as the patients are not uniquely identified, and multiple visits may belong to a single patient.

Is anyone aware of a specific theoretical approach to calculating incidence and prevalence based on this kind of data set, perhaps with some additional demographic information on the population?

For example, when Wolfram Alpha is [queried for a specific disease code](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ICD-9+631), it returns an estimate of the incidence and prevalence based on the NAMCS data set "weighted for US demographics."

One approach that I can think of is using age and sex data to divide patient visits into "pools" (e.g. females of age 35) and then weighting the number of patients in each pool based on demographics (the percentage of the real population that is composed of such patients). Once this is done, visits could be interpreted as "regular patients" and incidence and prevalence calculated in the normal way. However, I'm not sure if this is a theoretically sound approach.

PS: tag suggestions appreciated.